# Set xstep and ystep pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this MWE. My question is how can set xsep and ystep in the axis so that they will properly appear, and without have to know in prior the range of values: `xtick={0,0.1,...,1}`, `ytick={80,85,...,120}`. For example, for `x`, I would like to have only something like `xstep=0.1`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
x1       y1
86.173   0  
92.9831  0.052631 
93.9947  0.105263
94.6829  0.157895
95.2628  0.210526
95.8316  0.263158   
96.3317  0.315789   
96.7983  0.368421   
97.2488  0.421053   
97.6326  0.473684   
98.0416  0.526316   
98.4448  0.578947   
98.9012  0.631579   
99.3715  0.684211   
99.908   0.736842   
100.46   0.789474   
101.202  0.842105   
102.183  0.894737   
103.592  0.947368
113.909  1
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    xmin=80,xmax=120,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xtick={0,0.1,...,1},
    ytick={80,85,...,120},
    legend style={%
        legend pos=south east,
        legend cell align=left,
    },
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\selectcolormodel{gray}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[mark=square] table[x=x1, y=y1] {\jobname.dat};
        \legend{Testing}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics{\jobname.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a WE allright but no MWE. `minor x tick num` is an option.

Comment: I will give a look to that option.

Comment: @percusse I would also to print the numbers below the tick.

Comment: I thought in defining the `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, xstep, ystep` outside the `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}` and use them later, and use `xtick={\xmin,\xmin+\xstep,...,\xmax},`, but that way `\xmin+\xstep` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still force your way with the idea you have given in the comments. But your workflow is quite interesting though I don't have any idea why you would want that. Also `compat=newest` will break your code if a future release decides to change an option you have used.

Here we embed the minimum and maximum declarations into a custom style and inside the style we temporarily make a small computation. It might be slight overkill but take it as a proof of concept. I still think that manual approach would be easier but it's just my opinion.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{helvet}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
x1       y1
86.173   0  
92.9831  0.052631 
93.9947  0.105263
94.6829  0.157895
95.2628  0.210526
95.8316  0.263158   
96.3317  0.315789   
96.7983  0.368421   
97.2488  0.421053   
97.6326  0.473684   
98.0416  0.526316   
98.4448  0.578947   
98.9012  0.631579   
99.3715  0.684211   
99.908   0.736842   
100.46   0.789474   
101.202  0.842105   
102.183  0.894737   
103.592  0.947368
113.909  1
}\mytable


\pgfplotsset{mytick x interval/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    xmin=#1,xmax=#3,myincrement={#1}{#2},
    xtick={#1,\myval,...,#3}
    },
    myincrement/.code 2 args={\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\xdef\myval{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    legend style={%
        legend pos=south east,
        legend cell align=left,
    },
    mytick x interval=80:5:120,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\selectcolormodel{gray}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[mark=square] table[x=x1, y=y1] {\mytable};
        \legend{Testing}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code seems good. I will try it later and wait to see if other responses come.

Comment: I needed that code to generate multiple graphics so that it was easy to change limits and the scale. In the first MWE I used also `tikzscale` because I needed to exactly resize some plots. I adapted it to work also with `y axis` and it does work nicely.